# Read a RTF File and Remove the dynamic text

Tags: c#, asp.net, winforms, visual-studio-2005, rtf

My RTF File contains a text in the beginning like below:

**{\rtf1\ansi\ansicpg1252\deff0\deflang1033{\fonttbl{\f0\fnil\fcharset0 Trebuchet MS;}{\f1\fswiss\fprq2\fcharset0 Verdana;}{\f2\fnil\fcharset0 Tahoma;}{\f3\fnil\fcharset0 Arial;}{\f4\froman\fprq2\fcharset0 Times New Roman;}}**

How can i Read the RTF File and replace with anything i wish?

Comment: The text that is generated contain font names and that is totally dynamic (i.e depending on user selection). Say instead it could be Arial, Verdana & Lucidia Handwriting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to generate the RTF Header yourself you should take a look at the [RTF Spec](http://www.biblioscape.com/rtf15_spec.htm#Heading6).
Otherwise you might be able to simply use the RichTextBox-Control, set the font-style/color etc. and get the header from the RTFText-Property.

Comment: Thanks for comment. How to use Richtextbox to read contents of RTF?

Comment: You could simply read the entire RTF-File contents into a string (using File.ReadAllText or similar) and set the RichTextBox.RTF Property.